# How to get descendant nodes from XML based on an attribute

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I'm trying to get descendant children of a node:

```
require 'nokogiri'

@doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open('data/20160521RHIL0.xml'))
nom_id = @doc.xpath('//race/nomination/@id')

race_id.each do |x|
  puts race_id.traverse {|race_id| puts nom_id }
end
```

I'm looking at two sources of info:

1. The documentation for [`XML:Node`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node), which has

   ```
   Nokogiri::XML::Node#children
   ```
2. sparklemotion's [Cheat-sheet](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/wiki/Cheat-sheet):

   ```
   node.traverse {|node| } # yields all children and self to a block, _recursivel
   ```

---

This is my test XML:

```
<meeting id="42977">
  <race id="215411">
    <nomination number="8" saddlecloth="8" horse="Chipanda" id="198926" />
    <nomination number="2" saddlecloth="2" horse="Chifries" id="198965" />
    <nomination number="1" saddlecloth="1" horse="Itpanda" id="199260" />
  </race>
  <race id="215412">
    <nomination number="1" saddlecloth="1" horse="Ruby" id="199634" />
    <nomination number="2" saddlecloth="2" horse="Gems" id="208926" />
    <nomination number="3" saddlecloth="3" horse="Rock" id="122923" />
  </race>
</meeting>
```

I can use XPath to easily get the race `id`:

```
require 'nokogiri'                                                                                                                      

  @doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open('data/20160521RHIL0.xml'))                                                                               

  race_id = @doc.xpath('//race/@id')                                                                                                      
  nom_id = @doc.xpath('//race/nomination/@id')  

  ...
  215411
  215412
```

How can I get the nodes nomination id and number of just the `race_id` 215411 and store it to a hash (like below)?

```
{215411 => [{id:198926, number:8},{id:198965, number:2}]}
```

Comment: You generally don't want to use `traverse`, but instead want to cherry-pick specific nodes. `traverse` on a node that contains a lot of children can slow your code, whereas a search, using `search` or `at` can target specific nodes quickly, skipping nodes you don't care about.

Comment: Why isn't `<nomination number="1" saddlecloth="1" horse="Itpanda" id="199260" />` being captured in your desired hash output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'nokogiri'

# xml data
str =<<-EOS
<meeting id="42977">
  <race id="215411">
    <nomination number="8" saddlecloth="8" horse="Chipanda" id="198926" />
    <nomination number="2" saddlecloth="2" horse="Chifries" id="198965" />
    <nomination number="1" saddlecloth="1" horse="Itpanda" id="199260" />
  </race>
  <race id="215412">
    <nomination number="1" saddlecloth="1" horse="Ruby" id="199634" />
    <nomination number="2" saddlecloth="2" horse="Gems" id="208926" />
    <nomination number="3" saddlecloth="3" horse="Rock" id="122923" />
  </race>
</meeting>
EOS

# create doc
doc = Nokogiri::XML(str)

# clean; via http://stackoverflow.com/a/1528247
doc.xpath('//text()[not(normalize-space())]').remove

# parse doc
parsed_doc = doc.xpath('//race').inject({}) {|h,x| h[x.get_attribute('id').to_i] = x.children.map {|y| {id: y.get_attribute('id').to_i, number: y.get_attribute('number').to_i}}; h}
# {215411=>
#  [{:id=>198926, :number=>8},
#   {:id=>198965, :number=>2},
#   {:id=>199260, :number=>1}],
# 215412=>
#  [{:id=>199634, :number=>1},
#   {:id=>208926, :number=>2},
#   {:id=>122923, :number=>3}]}

# select via id
parsed_doc.select {|k,v| k == 215411}
# {215411=>
#  [{:id=>198926, :number=>8},
#   {:id=>198965, :number=>2},
#   {:id=>199260, :number=>1}]}
```

Here's the one-liner as a multi-liner:

```
parsed_doc = doc.xpath('//race').inject({}) do |h,x|
  h[x.get_attribute('id').to_i] = x.children.map do |y|
    {
      id: y.get_attribute('id').to_i,
      number: y.get_attribute('number').to_i
    }
  end
  h
end
```

Comment: do you know what the deal with inject is, rubocop code warns on it say use each with instead? Is it being deprecated?

Comment: Found the reasoning here https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/master/lib/rubocop/cop/style/each_with_object.rb

Comment: Instead of `inject` using `each_with_object` is better because it doesn't require returning the object as the final expression in the block. `each` doesn't do the same thing as `inject`.

Comment: If you don't use `children` then you can ignore removing the text nodes when parsing.

Comment: I generally agree, although it boils down to opinion (regardless of benchmarks). Using `Hash#merge!` the block becomes interchangeable between the two enumerable methods with the same result: `doc.xpath('//race').each_with_object({}) {|x,h| h.merge!(x.get_attribute('id').to_i => x.children.map {|y| {id: y.get_attribute('id').to_i, number: y.get_attribute('number').to_i}})}`

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<meeting id="42977">
  <race id="215411">
    <nomination number="8" saddlecloth="8" horse="Chipanda" id="198926" />
    <nomination number="2" saddlecloth="2" horse="Chifries" id="198965" />
    <nomination number="1" saddlecloth="1" horse="Itpanda" id="199260" />
  </race>
  <race id="215412">
    <nomination number="1" saddlecloth="1" horse="Ruby" id="199634" />
    <nomination number="2" saddlecloth="2" horse="Gems" id="208926" />
    <nomination number="3" saddlecloth="3" horse="Rock" id="122923" />
  </race>
</meeting>
EOT

race_id = 215411
nominations = doc.at("race[id='#{race_id}']") 
   .search('nomination')
   .map{ |nomination|
     {
      number: nomination['number'].to_i,
      id: nomination['id'].to_i
     }
   }

{race_id => nominations}
# => {215411=>[{:number=>8, :id=>198926}, {:number=>2, :id=>198965}, {:number=>1, :id=>199260}]}
```

`race[id='#{race_id}']` is building a CSS selector to find just the desired node. Then it's easy to find the desired `nomination` nodes.

Note, I don't use `children` or `traverse` because they'll return all nodes, including text nodes, not just element nodes. I'd have to use additional logic to ignore the text nodes, which would waste time and space.

Your question isn't clear about this, but if you wanted to return the information for all races, it's a simple tweak:

```
doc.search('race').map{ |race|
  nominations = race.search('nomination')
     .map{ |nomination|
       {
        number: nomination['number'].to_i,
        id: nomination['id'].to_i
       }
     }

  {race['id'].to_i => nominations}
}
# => [{215411=>[{:number=>8, :id=>198926}, {:number=>2, :id=>198965}, {:number=>1, :id=>199260}]}, {215412=>[{:number=>1, :id=>199634}, {:number=>2, :id=>208926}, {:number=>3, :id=>122923}]}]
```

Comment: yours ends up the far more adaptable code for applying further searching, thank you for the answer.

Comment: I try to write code that's easily maintainable. Not that I need the points, but as a FYI, you can always change your selected answer within a grace period. Sometimes people select one because it's all that's available within a short time period, but since SO is an international site answers can trickle in for days. It's always good to wait at least a day to give the world a chance to weigh in.